# how to position the arrow of a selection list

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

as shown in the code below, i have `clr-select-container` with some attributes specified as shown.in the attached screen-shot, it shows the `clr-select-container`.

the problem i am facing is, the overturned arrow is few pixels away from the `clr-select-container`. i want to placed at the end of the `clr-select-container` just like the other `clr-select-container` shown in the screen-shot.
the other,`clr-select-container` are developed following the same approach i developed the one mentioned below in the code section.

i do not know why the other `clr-select-container` has a properly positioned overturned arrow except the one in the code
i hope my point is clear

**code**:

```
<div *ngIf="true" id="idAppRatesSelectionDiv">
    <clr-select-container id="idAppRatesSelectionContainer">
        <label id="idAppRatesLablel"> {{"LABELS.App_Rate" | translate }}:</label>
        <select id="idAppRatesSelectionMenu" clrSelect name="appRatesTypes" [(ngModel)]="iAppRatesSelectionPasser.appRateSelected" (change)="onAppRateSelected($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let appRateOfProduct of appRatesOfProduct" [ngValue]="appRateOfProduct">{{appRateOfProduct}}</option>
        </select>
</clr-select-container>
</div>
```

**image**

[image]

Comment: You can click the computed tab in the control panel,to see which properties lead to  this result

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS background-position: eg: background-position: 100% 100%;

Comment: in which tag please

Comment: In the :after css